# How to get data HasMany() using WhereHas in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many, wherehas

I want to get data from my table " Package " by using its model " Package "
and in this model " Package " it have a HasMany() named histories() relation to model " History "

so i want to only get data that have histories

here is my controller

```
public function getIncomeMPW(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        $this->getSearch($request);
        $query = new Package();
        $query->with(['histories', 'items', 'items.prices', 'origin_regency', 'origin_district', 'origin_sub_district', 'destination_regency', 'destination_district', 'destination_sub_district', 'code', 'attachments']);

        $query->whereHas('histories', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('partner_id');
        });

        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

        return (new Response(Response::RC_SUCCESS, $this->query->paginate(request('per_page', 15))))->json();
    }

}
```

here is my Package model relation histories HasMany()

```
public function histories(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(History::class, 'package_id', 'id');
}
```

and last here is my response that showing right now

[image]

i already try using whereHas(), Has(), whereDoesntHave(), and its seems like there is no impact on my response, can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Hi. Please paste your code here and don't use images.

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei done, can you help me ?

Comment: Are you sure `$query = new Package();` is actually creating a query? I've never seen this syntax. Can you try `$query = Package::with(['histories' ...`?

Comment: fyi, i already can show the data like in the screenshot, but the only thing i want is to filter the data that doesnt have histories to not showing in my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your response you simply access a different query as it seems.

```
return (new Response(Response::RC_SUCCESS, $this->query->paginate(request('per_page', 15))))->json();
```

Uses `$this->query`

While

```
$query = new Package();
$query->with(['histories', 'items', 'items.prices', 'origin_regency', 'origin_district', 'origin_sub_district', 'destination_regency', 'destination_district', 'destination_sub_district', 'code', 'attachments']);

$query->whereHas('histories', function (Builder $query) {
  $query->whereNotNull('partner_id');
});

$query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```

Defines a `$query` without `$this`. I'd expect your `$this->getSearch($request);` to define $this->query (as the function is not posted in the question, i cannot tell). So either remove `$this` in your response - or change everything to `$this` and ensure to now overwrite it in the first line.

Quickfix should be

```
return (new Response(Response::RC_SUCCESS, $query->paginate(request('per_page', 15))))->json();
```

UPDATE:

Quick answer: Change

```
return (new Response(Response::RC_SUCCESS, $this->query->paginate(request('per_page', 15))))->json();
```

To

```
return (new Response(Response::RC_SUCCESS, $query->paginate(request('per_page', 15))))->json();
```

Comment: thank you for your attention to my question, but it seems like that doesnt fix my whereHas problem, i already put wherehas in my controller code but the response keep showing the data that have empty histories []

Comment: Well then you obviously did not post enough of your code. You clearly don't reference the same query in your response as you do when setting it up. Hence, the `whereHas` you share in your code has no effect at all. What should `i already put wherehas in my controller code`even mean? You only shared your controller?! It doesn't seem you fully read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wwhat ***whereHas*** and ***whereDoesntHave*** functions do in the backstage is that they make a sub query such as:

```
Select * from packages where exists (select * from histories where CONDITIONS YOU HAVE MENTIONED)
```

And the problem here is that when you use ***with*** method you eager load table history which adds one extra query that is not related to the first one such as:

```
Select * from histories where package_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

So since we cleared that out, what I suggest you do is that you assign a function to a variable in this way:

```
$historyFunction = function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('partner_id');
        };
```

and than call it in ***with*** and in ***whereHas*** methods as shown below:

```
 $query->with(['histories' => $historyFunction, otherRelations... ]);
 $query->whereHas('histories', $historyFunction);
```

And what this does is that it tells eloquent: When you eager load Histories relationship add this conditions to the query you are about to make.